# Sprint boot - get environment or active profiles in logback.groovy

Tags: spring-boot, logback-groovy

In logback-spring.xml I know it's possible to access environment properties (in my case the active profile) with  but I'm looking for the groovy equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no equivalent for `logback.groovy`. As things stand, if you want to access the environment or the active profiles in your logging configuration you'll need to use `logback-spring.xml`.

If you'd like to see equivalent support in `logback.groovy`, please [open an enhancement request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/new).

Answer (score 1):

This is the way:

```
import static org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.ACTIVE_PROFILES_PROPERTY_NAME

def profiles = (System.getProperty(ACTIVE_PROFILES_PROPERTY_NAME) ?: '').split(',')
```

Then use like

```
if (profiles.contains('DEV')) {
...
}
```